# How to add input field using jQuery and call Ajax into new input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am using a table with input fields. I use jQuery for adding new row/ input field, and then I want to call Ajax into new row/input field. But its not working. Because it's not filling up the condition of `document.ready()` function..

here is my html form:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Account Name:</th>
    <th>Branch:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
             <input type="text" name="ac_name" class="auto-search-ac">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="branch">
        </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

Script for add new row in the table ( It is working perfectly) :

```
<script>
$(document).on("focus",'#table tr:last-child td:last-child',function() {
        //append the new row here.
        var table = $("#table");

        table.append('<tr>\
        <td style="width:250px;"><div> <input type="text" name="ac_name" class="auto-search-ac"></div>\
         </td>\
        <td><div><input type="text" name="branch"></div>\
        </td>\
       </tr>');
   });
   </script>
```

Ajax call into new inserted input field:: (in first row - ajax is working nicely)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".auto-search-ac").autocomplete({
    source: "/ca-list",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.auto-search-ac').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#ca-id-val').val(ui.item.ca_id);
    }
});

</script>
```

Note That :: I am using all scripts and html in Modal. In First row, everything is OK.

after adding new row by jQuery then I can not call ajax. May it could be the issue of `document.ready()`.

Question : how may I call any script/ajax/jQuery after adding a new input field/row using jquery in html ? Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: `auto-search-ac` in the row is `class` and in the `autocomplete`'s script is `id`

Comment: @MoshFeu :: I have updated .. please have a look

Comment: Have @Rayon Dabre answer you the question?

Comment: @MoshFeu :: still no results found. in very first row it is working but from 2nd row its not working

Comment: The answer of @Rayon Dabre seems right for me. A. Ask him for more explanation. B. Any errors in the `console`? C. Do you have a public URL (or can you create one) for this? So we could debug it with you.

Comment: @MoshFeu :: I am agree with you. Lets play together: here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/FRbcr/69/

Comment: @MoshFeu : I got my answer from Rayon Dabre. Its superb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class selector as you do not have element having is as `auto-search-ac`. After appending element, find element having class as `auto-search-ac` from the appended `tr` and initialize `autocomplete`

Try this:

```js
$(".auto-search-ac").autocomplete({
  source: "/ca-list",
  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.value);
    alert(ui.item.ca_id);
  }
});


$(document).on("focus", '#table tr:last-child td:last-child', function() {
  var table = $("#table");
  var element = '<tr>\
        <td style="width:250px;"><div> <input type="text" name="ac_name" class="auto-search-ac"></div>\
         </td>\
        <td><div><input type="text" name="branch"></div>\
        </td>\
       </tr>';
  table.append(element);

  $("#table tr:last-child").find(".auto-search-ac").autocomplete({
    source: "/ca-list",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert(ui.item.value);
      alert(ui.item.ca_id);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Name:</th>
      <th>Branch:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="ac_name" class="auto-search-ac">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="branch">
      </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9R4cV/570/)

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre:: it's not working while inserting new input field.

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre: in very first row it is working but from 2nd row its not working

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre : lets try to share into Filldle ... but problem will be autocomplete data

Comment: @ Ryaon Dabre :: Just Awesome. its perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ryaon Dabre :: what is the difference in this fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/FRbcr/70/   ???

Comment: You have not included `jQuery UI`..Thats it..[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/FRbcr/71/) provided by you

Comment: Yeah got it. Thank you so much. !